# How can I get acess to currentSession when not using Hibernate

Tags: mongodb, grails

I am using MongoDB as my primary datastore so I dont want to use the hibernate plugin for some reason and  removed it from `BuildConfig.groovy`.

My question is when I was using **Hibernate** accessing `currentSession` was simple:
I just inject `sessionFactory` on my service then do `sessionFactory.currentSession`

*How do I get to handle of `currentSession` when not using Hibernate?*

Answer (score 0):

All versions of GORM support the static `withSession` method (see the docs [here](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withSession.html)):

```
SomeDomainClass.withSession { session ->
   ...
}
```

Like `withTransaction` it doesn't matter which domain class you call it on.